# Is it possible to access the content generated by a css :before rule?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm experimenting with using html5 and [css counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS_Counters) to number the figures in a document. The figure numbering css is working, but I need to be able to generate cross reference that include the figure numbers.

Is there any way to access those values via javascript? The counter code I am using is:

```
body { counter-reset: section; }
section { counter-reset: figure;
          counter-increment: section; }
section section { counter-reset: section; }
section > h1:before { content: counters(section, '.'); }
.figure > .caption:before {
  counter-increment: figure;
  content: 'Figure ' counters(section, '.') '-' counter(figure); }
section > h1:before, .figure > .caption:before { margin-right: .5em; }
```

Comment: Use your browser's DOM inspector so see if the numbers appear in DOM. If that is the case, you can access it by JavaScript DOM.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content):

> Generated content does not alter the
>   document tree. In particular, it is
>   not fed back to the document language
>   processor (e.g., for reparsing).

In other words, it appears as if the `content` CSS attribute merely adds text "styling" to the page, without affecting the document structure. The DOM is not aware of this styling and thus, Javascript cannot access it.